# How can I use hasNextInt() to catch an exception? I need Int but if input is character, that is bad

Tags: java, exception

I have been trying to stop the exceptions but I cannot figure out how.
I tried `parseInt`, `java.util.NormalExceptionMismatch` etc.

Does anyone have any insight how to fix this problem? Formatting is a bit off due to copy and paste.

```
do
{
   System.out.print(
           "How many integers shall we compare? (Enter a positive integer):");
   select = intFind.nextInt();
   if (!intFind.hasNextInt()) 
       intFind.next();
       {
           // Display the following text in the event of an invalid input
           System.out.println("Invalid input!");
       }
}while(select < 0)
```

Other methods I have tried :

```
 do
    {
       System.out.print(
                   "How many integers shall we compare? (Enter a positive integer):");
       select = intFind.nextInt();
       {
            try{
                   select = intFind.nextInt();
               }catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e)
            {
               // Display the following text in the event of an invalid input
               System.out.println("Invalid input!");
               return;
            }
       }
    }while(select < 0)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question - your code has no try/catch...

Comment: I tried try/catch and couldn't get it to work. SO i changed to hasNextInt

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you expect these code samples would do and they don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to skip everything until you get an integer. This code here skips any input except an integer.

As long as there is no integer available (while (!in.hasNextInt())) discard the available input (in.next). When integer is available - read it (int num = in.nextInt();)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            in.next();
        }
        int num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Thank you for choosing " + num + " today.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick sample of how to catch exceptions:

```
int exceptionSample()
{
    int num = 0;
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        // prompt for input
        // inputStr = read input
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
            done = true;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            // Error msg
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the best practice is to use `nextLine()` to get a String input, then `parseInt` it to get the integer. If unparsable, just complain back to the user and request re-entry.

Remember you may have to do a second `nextLine()` (discard the input) to clear up the buffer.